# remove namespace using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi i am new to xml and i'm using xslt to remove namespaces.Below is the input code.

```
<ks6:newRequest xmlns:ks6="http://example.com/connector/ssw" xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ks3="com.newtech.kake.notification"
xmlns:ks5="com.newtech.alert" xmlns:ks7="http://notification.newtech.com">
    <ks5:new book = "5073">
        <ks5:entityId>2314</ks5:entityId>
        <ks5:entityName>newReq</ks5:entityName>
    </ks5:new>
    <ks3:new2>
       <ks3:entityId>2315</ks3:entityId>
        <ks3:entityName>newReq2</ks3:entityName>
    </k3:new2>
</ks6:newRequest>
```

What i want to do is to remove the namespace ks6 together with its URI i.e. its xmlns too and use namespace ks5 instead of ks6.
Here, how my output should look.

```
<ks5:newRequest xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ks3="com.newtech.kake.notification"
    xmlns:ks5="com.newtech.alert" xmlns:ks7="http://notification.newtech.com">
        <ks5:new book = "5073">
            <ks5:entityId>2314</ks5:entityId>
            <ks5:entityName>newReq</ks5:entityName>
        </ks5:new>
       <ks3:new2>
           <ks3:entityId>2315</ks3:entityId>
           <ks3:entityName>newReq2</ks3:entityName>
       </k3:new2>
    </ks5:newRequest>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Which XSLT processor, which XSLT version do you use, what have you tried?

Comment: `xsl:element` takes a `namespace` argument, and xpath has `local-name` etc.

Comment: I am using eclipse neon or sometime online compiler. I don't have any work related to xslt its just the first and last so i was just hoping if someone can help.I have searched thoroughly but i could'nt find what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XSLT, you have to write templates matching those nodes you want to transform, as in your case you want to change the namespace of the elements in a certain namespace and want to strip the namespace from the other elements you need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(. = 'http://example.com/connector/ssw')]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ks6:*" xmlns:ks6="http://example.com/connector/ssw">
        <xsl:element name="ks5:{local-name()}" namespace="com.newtech.alert">
            <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(. = 'http://example.com/connector/ssw')]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```